# M2M field was required and then changed to blank=True

Tags: django, django-migrations

I've got 2 models `Task` and `TaskType`. Task could have several types and they are required. Now new requirements dictate that types are unnecessary and should be removed. I set `blank=True` in `Task` field called `types` and run migration. Actually migration was created but didn't applied to DB.

```py
class TaskType(Base):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Task(Base):
    ...
    # initially there was only one parameter - TaskType
    types = models.ManyToManyField(TaskType, blank=True)
    ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting to be applied to the db here.

Comment: `blank=True` means that the field is not editable, etc. It has little to do with the database itself.

Comment: Okay, if it's not so important parameter for db, then why I'm getting error like `types field can't be null`?

Comment: @nrgx because `null` refers to the database, while `blank` refers to frontend UI such as forms. If you set `blank=True` on a model field you should also set `null=True`.

Comment: It's redundant to write `null=True` for M2M field. This is some kind of bug that triggers validation error. I already set it up as `blank=True` and still getting that error. Even if I removed migrations from project deleted tables from DB and migrations from `django_migrations` table that related to app.

Comment: show us the exact error trace you're getting and what triggers it.